# How can i achieve displaying the bottombar on top of the soft keyboard in android compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-jetpack-compose-material3

[image]

Im not sure on how i can place the bottombar ontop of the keyboard when its visible

[image]

i want the bottombar to show at that position when the keyboard is up

presently the keyboard overlay the bottombar making it difficult to access the bottombar stylings

Answer (score 0):

Use `Modifier.imePadding()` on your bottomBar, this will always keep the bottomBar above the keyboard when it's visible.

```kotlin
BottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier.imePadding()) {}
```

Comment: tried it, didn't work, the keyboard overlay still occurred

Comment: i found away around it after going through the insets doc https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets